# RotateLeft for multidimensional string array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

My code is to generate  multidimensional by random
i do this step
but i want to make rotateLeft for the random array by one shift

This is my array

```
String  [][] Sec ={
                        {"S1","--","S5","S2","S4"},
                        {"S3","S4","S5","S3","S7"},
                        {"S1","--","S7","--","--"},
                        {"S2","--","S5","S6","S3"},
                        {"--","s1","S2","S6","S4"}
                        };
```

This the random function

```
for (int  i=0 ; i<Sec.length; i++ )
{
    for (int j=0 ; j<Sec[i].length; j++ )
    {
        int i1 = (int) (Math.random()* Sec.length);
        int j1 = (int) (Math.random()* Sec[i].length);

        String temp = Sec[i][j];
        Sec[i][j] =  Sec[i1][j1];
        Sec[i1][j1] =temp;

    } //end for 1
    }//end for2
```

And this the print of random array

```
for (int  i=0 ; i<Sec.length; i++ )
{

      System.out.print("p"+ r1++ +"     " );

    for (int j=0 ; j <Sec.length; j++ )
    {
        System.out.print(Sec[j][i] + "    ");

    }
```

Now i want **help me** to make rotateLeft for this random array and print it again for two time

The output is:

```
p1     S5    S6    S3    S1    S5    

p2     --    --    S6    S5    --    

p3     S4    S4    S7    S2    S4    

p4     S2    --    --    --    S3    

p5     S3    S7    s1    S2    S1
```

And i wish the out put for random like this ( MAKE ONE SHIFT TO CHANG THE ORDER OF ELEMNT)

```
p1      S1     S5    S6    S3    S1        

p2      S5     --    --    S6    S5        

p3      --     S4    S4    S7    S2       

p4      S4     S2    --    --    --      

p5      S3     S3    S7    s1    S2
```

Comment: How can you expect any particular output when you apply a random function? The definition of random means that you cannot predict the result. --- How is randomly swapping values in any way a "rotate"? It's called a *shuffle*, if anything.

Comment: What is `r1`? Where is it defined?

Comment: @Andreas . I just assumed that r1 == i.

Comment: @yyttr3 I'm assuming there's a `int r1 = 1` right before the loop, but it's not shown, and it's entirely unnecessary, since `r1++` could just be `(i+1)`. Anyway, I was just trying to point out the code is incomplete. I'm more interested in a response to my first comment tho. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas i know is give a random output every time , i but this for explain just

Comment: @Andreas thr r value is just count number for the row p1 ,p2, p3 < this is r in the out put

Comment: @NjoodAlassmi If all you want to know is how to shift the matrix 1 element to the right, then why are you including all that other stuff about randomly shuffling the array? Please read "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)". You are confusing/obscuring the question with all the fluff, assuming I'm now understanding what you really want.

Comment: @Andreas i'm sorry , my program have two step random the element of array then the 2step make one shift for the element

Comment: @NjoodAlassmi My point is that anything before the "**help me**" is meaningless and the question starts there, with "I have this: *`example`*" and "I want to shift one right to get this: *`example`*". To that question, the answer is that [questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the **work done so far** to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). So, show us what you have tried for the shift operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're rotating like that then it would make more sense to operate on a flat array rather than on a matrix.  If you did this then you could just take the last element of the array **LastE** and append that to the front of the array, deleting the last element.

```
// PSEUDOCODE
flat_array = matrix.flatten
LastE      = flat_array[len(flat_array)-1]
TailE      = flat_array.subset(0,len(flat_array)-2)

rotated    = TailE.prepend(LastE)
```

After you get your rotated array you can either turn this back into a matrix or just operate on the array as if it was a matrix.

Comment: @answered   plz can you explain where i use this in my code :(

Comment: @Njood No, because I don't know enough about your code. Anyways, if you know your material you should be able to implement the concept. Google and learn how to do this.